# Objective C - better way to write my if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

It's not an actual problem but it is frustrating me.. 
I was looking for a better way to right an IF statement with multiple values that can be accepted.

For example:

```
if ([[myJson objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue] == 0 || [[myJson objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue] ==  3)
```

Isn't there any way to write something like:

```
if ([[myJson objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue] == 0 | 3)
{

}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: This question is mostly a matter of taste/preference.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should probably use 'integerValue' rather than 'intValue'.  'integerValue' returns an NSInteger vs. an int

Answer (score 8):

No, not really. You could do this:

```
int pages = [[myJson objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue];
if (pages == 0 || pages == 3)
```

That's what I would recommend. The code you posted is both less efficient and harder to maintain than the code I show.

In your code you actually invoke the `objectForKey` and `intValue` methods twice on the same object.

Plus if at some point in the future you change the key value, or the variable name, you have to make the same edit in 2 places, which is more work and adds another chance to introduce a new copy/paste error.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other valid answers, you could use a switch:

```
int numberOfPages = [[myJson objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue];
switch (numberOfPages) {
    case 0:
    case 3: {
        NSLog(@"Is 0 or 3");
        break;
    }
    default: {
        NSLog(@"Is NOT 0 or 3");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a much better method as it is clean and easier to read:

```
int x = [[myJson objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue];

if (x == 0 || x == 3) {

}
```

Comment: thanks David, i have made the required changes.

Comment: I'd encourage the use of a more descriptive variable name (e.g. `pages`).

Answer (score 1):

You are highly optimistic there.

If `myJson` is not an `NSDictionary` your app will crash.

If `myJson[@"pages"]` is not an `NSNumber` then your app will crash.

If `myJson[@"pages"]` does not exist then intValue will return 0.

If `myJson[@"pages"]` has a value of 0.9 or 3.7 then `intValue` will return 0 or 3.

I suggest you add a category to `NSDictionary` with a method like `integerValueForKey:` withDefault where you lookup an item, check that it is an `NSNumber` with an integer value, return that value or return the default value.

Comment: Good points. (voted) One quibble though: myJson [@"pages"] could be either an NSNumber or an NSString and it would work (NSString also responds to intValue/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Since I am the one who manage the server I know that myJson will always be NSDictionary (even though I verified this in my code nontheless). same for pages - always return a number.

Answer (score 0):

As David Rönnqvist pointed out, it is mostly a matter of preference. I would personally go with `NSArray` containing allowed values. This way you won't clutter your code with unnecessary `intValue` calls. Also adding another allowed value will only require adding a single value to an array instead of adding another condition inside `if` statement.

Note that you can use Objective-C literal syntax to make the code more concise.

```
NSArray *allowedValues = @[@0, @3];
if([allowedValues containsObject:myJson[@"pages"]]) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `[myJson objectForKey:@"pages"]` is an `NSNumber`. You could do this:

```
if([@[@0, @3] containsObject:[myJson objectForKey:@"pages"]])
```

And if `myJson` is an `NSDictionary` you could even shorten it to:

```
if([@[@0, @3] containsObject:myJson[@"pages"]])
```

It's not necessarily optimal, but it does provide you with a lot more flexibility when adding more values to check against, which it sounds like you're looking for as opposed to the fastest code. If you're just checking a few values I'm assuming speed of execution is not an issue.

---

Side note: this works because `NSArray`'s `containsObject:` method calls `isEqual:` on every object. `NSNumber`'s `isEqualToNumber:` gets called. This will also work with `NSString` instead of `NSNumber` if that's what you're working with. Just change the search array to hold `NSString` objects in that case.